# End loop in powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, if-statement

Heey guys,

I want a loop in the script but it needs to stop when I use else

```
do {


##script##



if ((Get-Service $service ).Status -eq "stopped") {
Write-Host 'Send email message, a service has been stopped'
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $mycredentials -Attachments $service_text -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$stopen = "stoppen"
}
else { write-host "re execute script" } while ((Get-Service $service ).Status -eq "stopped")
}
```

How can I end the loop in the else statement ?

Thanks

See the full script, The fault is in the end of the script.
The script needs to check it again if the service is running. And if the service stopped then I need to receive an email. And no I don't want to receive 200000000 emails just one :P

```
## PSVersion: Required Powershell V 3.0
## Author:  Gijs Liefers
## Script: If a service has been stopped you will receive an email
## Requirements: Internet connection, Port 587 open for mailing and run this script as administrator.

## Version 1.0       
## - Initial Release
## Date: 14-1-2015 

### Note: 
## - Set-Exexution Policy ## --
## if you want to run this script you have to set the ExecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned.
## To do this open Powershell run as Administrator and type Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned.
## Click on yes to all

### -- LOOP
$doetiehettest = Test-Path C:\Windows 






### --- Make Directory --- ####
########################################################################
# PowerShell checks, then creates a file and folder
Clear-Host
$Location = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services"
$LocationFile = "$env:userprofile\documents\"

If((Test-Path $Location) -eq $False) {
New-Item -Path $Locationfile -name "PS-Script-Services" -ItemType "directory" | out-null
    } # End of folder exists test



#region Main Variables
########################################################################
## -- Locations --  ## 
########################################################################
$documents         = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\"
$password_location = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Password.txt"
$username_location = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Username.txt"
$source_adres      = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Source.txt"
$destination_adres = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Destination.txt"
$SMTP_adres        = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\SMTP.txt"
$Service_text      = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Services.txt"
$Data_service      = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Output-Services.txt"
########################################################################

##############################################    

### -- Email information -- ###
##########################################
Write-host " "
Write-Host "Welcome to a automated script! You will receive a email if a specific service has been stopped" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor green
Write-host "All the files of this script are located on $documents" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-host "If you have any questions about this script send a mail to GijsLiefers@outlook.com" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor green
############################################


## Test-Path ##
$source_test = Test-Path $source_adres
$des_test    = Test-Path $destination_adres
$smtp_test   = Test-Path $SMTP_adres
$service_test = Test-Path $Service_text
$data_test    = Test-Path $Data_service
################################

#endregion

#-loop-# -- Email settings -- ##
If (($source_test -eq $false) -and ($des_test -eq $false) -and  ($smtp_test -eq $false))  {
Read-Host "What is the source mailadres? (inclucing @example.com)" | Out-file $source_adres
Read-Host "What is the destination mailadres? (inclucing @example.com)" | Out-file $destination_adres
Write-Host "This script using  SSL on port 587 for the SMTP server " -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
Read-Host "What is the smtp server? (Example: smtp.gmail.com" | Out-file $SMTP_adres
}

Else { 
Write-host " "
write-host "Are the email settings right? SMTP: $get_smtp, From (source): $get_source, To (destination): $get_dest" -BackgroundColor white -ForegroundColor Black
write-host "Otherwise edit the settingsfolder PS-Script-Services on the following path $documents" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
}


########### -- STORED CREDENTIAL CODE ###################################

## Test-Path ##
$FileExists = Test-Path $password_location, $username_location

#-loop-# -- Email Credentials -- ##
if  ($FileExists -eq $false) {
    Write-Host 'Credential file not found. Enter your username and password:' -ForegroundColor Red
    Read-Host "Enter Username from your email account most of the time don't add @example.com" | Out-File $username_location
    Read-Host "Enter Password from your email account" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $password_location
    $Username = get-content $username_location
    $Password = get-content $password_location | convertto-securestring
    $mycredentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username,$Password
    }
else {
    Write-Host "Using your stored credential file on path $password_location and $username_location " -ForegroundColor Green
    $Username = get-content $username_location
    $Password = get-content $password_location | convertto-securestring
    $mycredentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username,$Password
    }

### -- Get-Content -- ##
#############################################################################################
$get_smtp = Get-Content $SMTP_adres -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$get_source = Get-Content $source_adres -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$get_dest = Get-Content $destination_adres -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$service = Get-Content $Data_service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
##################################################################################################


#-loop-# -- Get-Service -- ##
if ($Data_test -eq $false) {
Write-Host "To view your Services go to Start --> en typ services, or go to Powershell and type get-service" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
write-host "Which Services do you want to monitor? (Example: `n Teamviewer `n BITS `n DHCP (Use a LIST !!!!)"
write-host "This script only works when a service has been stopped" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
New-Item $Data_service -Type file -Value "Add the services in a row and delete this rule!" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Out-Null
sleep 3
Invoke-Item $Data_service
sleep 25
}
else { write-host "The following services are selected: $service . Edit them if necessary. For editing Delete the folder $location" -BackgroundColor white -ForegroundColor Black
}

## - Just a test ## --


do {

## -- Attachment content # -- 
$service_input = Get-Content $Service_text -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


##############################################################################
##-- Attachment --##

Get-Service $service | Out-File $Service_text 

## -- Send Mail message -- ## 
##############################################################################
$title = "Incident! Service has been stopped on $env:COMPUTERNAME " 
$message = "Dear Sir/Madam,

There is a issue on the following server $env:Computername. One or multiple service(s) has been stopped.

Look at the attachment which service has been stopped
$service


We hope that we give you enough information to solve this problem

Kind Regards,

Powershell Automated Script

Tech support



 "


##############################################################################


#Establishes connection to MailServer with the specified user acccount and password.


## -- Note .. #-- 
## If you add the information for the first time there will be a error message ## .. Run the script again



$From = $get_source
$To = $get_dest
$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
$Subject = $title
$Body = $message
$SMTPServer = $get_smtp
$SMTPPort = "587"

if ((Get-Service $service ).Status -eq "stopped") {
Write-Host 'Send email message, a service has been stopped'
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $mycredentials -Attachments $service_text -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}


else { 
write-host "re execute script"
;break
} 


} while((Get-Service $service ).Status -eq "stopped")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you attempt to start the service if it's stopped? Or do you just want to continue spamming with emails until someone comes online and starts the service manually?

Comment: So, if the service if running, you want to keep the `do{}while()` loop running forever, checking the status? What then if the service stops at one point? Should the loop still continue? Throttle the emails? Introduce a delay?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break` keyword to break out of a loop:

```
$i = 0
do{
  if($i -lt 5)
  {
    $i++
  }
  else
  {
    break
  }
} while ($true)
```

or use the `while()` clause properly:

```
$i = 0
do{
  $i++
} while ($i -lt 5)
```

Comment: `

}
else { 
write-host "re execute script"
break
}  
}

At C:\Users\gijs\OneDrive\! Mijn Documenten\10 - Scripts\Send email if service stopped\Send-email-if-service-has-stopped.ps1:195 char:2
+ }
+  ~
Missing while or until keyword in do loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingWhileOrUntilInDoWhile `

Comment: Sorry, typo in my answer, it's updated now. You'll also need a `;` before `break` inside your `else` block

Comment: else { 
write-host "re execute script"
;break
}

Comment: Exactly, and then `while((Get-Service $service ).Status -eq "stopped")` *outside* the `do{}` block

Comment: it's not working :( 

The script has to run again if a service is running. If a service has been stopped I need te receive a email

Comment: You have to make up your mind - do you want to keep the loop running or not? If you update your question with details about what you're acutally trying to *accomplish*, I may be able to help you